# Bind list of string from appsettings.json

Tags: c#, .net-core, appsettings

I have the following list of string defined in my appSettings

```
 "AllowedGroups": [ "support", "admin", "dev" ]
```

and I want to bind it to a class in the startup for dependency injection .

This is my model class

```
  public class AllowedGroups
    {
        public List<string> Groups { get; set; }
    }
```

This is how I tried to bind it.

```
   services.Configure<AllowedGroups>(Configuration.GetSection("AllowedGroups"));
```

I would like to keep the appsettings file in this format and I don't know how should I define de model class accordingly and how to bind it.
I'm aware that he might expect to have `"AllowedGroups":{Groups: [ "support", "admin", "dev" ]}` with the current model

Comment: If you want that JSON to stay the same, you need to change the class or build it manually as per @Guru's answer. It all feels a little hacky though, I think changing the JSON is the most sensible option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to keep config structure you can just resolve everything "raw":

```
var allowedGroups = Configuration.GetSection("AllowedGroups").Get<List<string>>();
services.AddSingleton(new AllowedGroups {Groups = allowedGroups});
```

Note that this will just register the `AllowedGroups` not the [options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-5.0) as `Configure` does. To register options you can use next overload of [`Configure`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.optionsservicecollectionextensions.configure?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_OptionsServiceCollectionExtensions_Configure__1_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection_System_Action___0__):

```
services.Configure<AllowedGroups>(allowedGroups =>
    allowedGroups.Groups = Configuration.GetSection("AllowedGroups").Get<List<string>>());
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do this:

```
_config.GetConfigSection("AllowedGroups").GetChildren().ToList();
```

_config being derived from IConfiguration.